# "По большому счету" українською

Tags: переклад, from-russian, фразеологізми, граматика, сталий-вираз

Чи існує український відповідник(и) до російського **"по большому счету"**?

Чи буде правильним сказати "**по-великому рахунку**" або "**за великим рахунком**"?

Comment: Цікаво чому даному питанню ставлять мінуси? Є якесь правило, яке забороняє подібні питання ставити?

Comment: @RomanMalkevych тому що це запитання не відповідає вимогам [How do I ask a good question?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), конкретно — пп. 1, 3. Див. також [Хороші питання і хороші відповіді](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/8). Шкода, що автор за майже 4 місяці не спробував виправити жодне зі своїх п'яти запитань (одне видалене). Шкода, що ніхто із спільноти не забажав допомогти авторові з редагуванням. Шкода, що ніхто з модераторів не втрутився, щоб пояснити авторові принципи роботи цього сайту і правила оформлення дописів.

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine то редагував інший Роман) Але всеодно дякую за відповідь. Мені здається, що загалом порушено проблему, яка варта того, щоб її вирішити. Бо в Україні часто говорять по большому счету, навіть україномовні.

Comment: @RomanMalkevych oops, перепрошую щодо авторства редагування. От що значить — дописувати уночі. :) я приберу той коментар, щоб не вводив в оману.

Comment: @RomanMalkevych Щодо мовних питань загалом: їх, дійсно, безліч! І при належному оформленні запитань, які порушують ці — дійсно, актуальні — проблеми, цей сайт міг би бути зразковим, залучати нових користувачів, лишатися цікавим для старих. Але це потребує двох речей: (1) спільного розуміння щодо якості дописів; щодо того, чим відрізняються хороші дописи від поганих; (1.а) особливо це стосується модераторів; (2) великого обсягу волонтерської роботи «простих» користувачів по модеруванню, редагуванню тощо. Ані першого, ані другого на цьому сайті, на жаль, не утворилося.

Answer (score 1):

### Загалом, великою мірою

Незважаючи, що ідіома "**за великим рахунком**" рясно зустрічається в творах українських письменників XX-століття, проте це пряма калька з російської мови.

Фразеологізм не несе жодного лексичного навантаження і вживається краще як [вставна фраза](https://www.dilovamova.com/index.php?page=4&dmua=71&tdmua=%C2%F1%F2%E0%E2%ED%B3-%F1%EB%EE%E2%E0-%B3-%F1%EB%EE%E2%EE%F1%EF%EE%EB%F3%F7%E5%ED%ED%FF-%E2-%E4%B3%EB%EE%E2%EE%EC%F3-%EC%EE%E2%EB%E5%ED%ED%B3) на етапі підведення логічного підсумку бесіди, наведення висновків або надання пропозиції, тому його можна замінити будь-яким зручним для використання українським вставним словом - **загалом**, **узагалі ж**, **переважно**, **здебільшого**, **та ін.**

[Святослав Караванський](https://maysterni.com/p2.htm) про цей вислів пише:

> **ЗА ВЕЛИКИМ РАХУНКОМ**
> У сучасних друкованих текстах часом натрапляєш на вирази, які можна зрозуміти, лише знаючи російську мову.
> Так, деякі автори полюбляють вираз **за великим рахунком**.  Узятий
> окремо вираз цей годі зрозуміти. Ось речення, де його вжито:
>
> ”Ідеології комунізму була протиставлена ідеологія свободи, що, **за**
> **великим рахунком**, сприяло розвитку технології виробництва”.
>
> З цього речення, можна зрозуміти, що вираз за великим рахунком вжито
> тут у значенні **”великою мірою”**.  Такий логічний шлях для
> зрозуміння цього виразу. Той же, хто знає російську мову зрозуміє його
> скоріше, згадавши російський, модний тепер, вираз **по большому
> счёту**.  Саме з цього виразу і ”здерто” українську кальку.  Іншими
> словами, українська мова ”збагатилася” коштом бездарного перекладу
> російської ідіоми та прищеплення її на український ґрунт. Вираз **за
> великим рахунком** не будить у нашій свідомості жодного образу, він
> геть незрозумілий тим, хто не знає мови ”старших (історично -
> молодших) братів”.  Вираз цей змушує нас для зрозуміння вдаватися до
> цієї мови, заразом навіюючи думку, що українська мова нездатна
> розвиватися без копіювання російських мовних зразків.

---

Також існує альтернативна гіпотеза щодо історії походження фрази та  її тлумачення. Та джерело не містить жодних роз'яснень або довідок яким чином "[за великим рахунком](https://naurok.com.ua/slovnik-frazeologizmiv-dlya-uchniv-ta-uchiteliv-17527.html)" потрапило з німецької мови в українську, тому наведену інформацію краще сприймати виключно як додаток до відповіді.

> Походження цього вислову пов’язане з німецьким містом Гамбург. Щороку
> тут відбувалися змагання циркових борців, на яких судді з’ясовували
> дійсні класи професійної боротьби, на відміну від циркових поєдинків,
> де часто практикували програші за домовленістю і панував дух наживи.
> Тому кваліфікацію борців визначали подвійно — за звичайним рахунком і
> за гамбурзьким, тобто за великим. Фразеологізм **«за великим рахунком»**
> означає **по-справжньому**, **як потрібно**, **зрозуміло як**.

Comment: − < рясно зустрічається в творах українських письменників XX-століття, проте це пряма калька з російської мови. > Докази?

Comment: @Sútnôstj, не розумію які саме докази? Що це калька? Або що совєтські письменники псували нею українську мову впродовж ХХ-століття, а дехто продовжує і понині? Додав посилання. Як не згодні, будь ласка, створіть окремий пост із власним обгрунтуванням тлумачення або додавайте аргументи до своїх заперечень.